# SP initiated SSO

Tags: angular, single-sign-on, okta, opensaml

I have an angular SPA (SP). My org uses Okta as our identity provider/ management. I want to enable users to use SP initiated SSO. Users have their own IDPs like okta, one login, etc., I can send the saml authn request to users IDP. Is there a way to send the saml response directly to okta for validation instead of going through SP?

Most of the solutions I see involve using something like a Java backend with opensaml to validate saml response. If my usual authentication is through angular SPA without using backend, what do I do after getting the saml response to my backend?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [**response from Okta Support**](https://devforum.okta.com/t/angular-with-saml/990/2), Angular SPA with SAML is not supported in Okta.

> Thank you for reaching out to Okta Support, my name is — and I’ll be handling your case.
> I checked available documentation and some outside sources, it would seem that Angular SPA with SAML is not a supported configuration.
> Here are the articles that I found, hopefully it helps in some way:

https://developer.okta.com/code/angular/okta_angular_sign-in_widget

https://developer.okta.com/code/angular/okta_angular_auth_js